What is the meaning of action of Galois group factors through some Gal(K/k)?
Let $L/k$ be a Galois extension of a field $k$ (finite or infinite) and let $  G = Gal(L/k). $ Let $G$ act on a finite set $X.$
What is the meaning of the action factors through $G  \to Gal(K/k)$ for some subfield $K$ of $L$ finite and Galois over $k$?

@kobe Consider making this an answer rather than a comment

It means that the morphism $G \to \text{Aut}(X)$ factors as a composition $G \to \text{Gal}(K/k) \to \text{Aut}(X)$.

Say $\phi : G \to Aut(X)$ the morphism. Do you mean that there exist a $\psi : Gal(K/k) \to Aut(X)$ such that $\phi = \psi \circ \pi$ where $\pi : G \to Gal(K/k)$ is the restriction map (which is surjective )??

Yes, @infinity_hunter.
